# Touch events for google maps on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my app I am using google maps and I am creating locations on the maps once the user right clicks. I have this event doing the trick for me

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function (e) {
    if (checkDistance(e.latLng)) {
        if (viewModel.haveRolesToDoStuffOnProjectLevel()) {
            geocoder.geocode({ location: e.latLng }, function (result) {
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    var data = {
                        name: result[0].formatted_address.split(",")[0],
                        location: e.latLng,
                        address: result[0].formatted_address
                    }
                    if (viewModel.oldLocation()) {
                        moveLocationCreate(data);
                    } else {
                        startLocationCreate(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Everything is working fine until I open the app in mobile. On mobile the *rightclick* event won't fire. I have searched to find a way to have something like long click on mobile but it is not working. Can anyone help me finding a solution for this?

Comment: might be of some use - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you try [this google maps event demo site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) on your phone/tablet, you would realize nothing happen even when you do a long click. It just means Google Maps support no tablet events.

But with jQuery, you can detect a long click, or other "mobile only" events. However, jQuery has no knowledge of the maps and, therefore, do tell you where you clicked on.

So one solution to that might be to use both, the [Google Maps Click event,](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) and the [jQuery tabhold event](https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/).

First, let `tabhold` set a flag, to indicate that this click function is from `tabhold`; then on the onclick function, check if this current click event is from tabhold, if so, perform the action.

I have a quick [demo on jsfiddle][4], I just copied and pasted some code so it looks kind of ugly. But hopefully it helps.

Comment: I ended up using hammer JS for the gestures. It is quite good library,